# Call segue on tap of UITextView swift?

Tags: swift

I have a UITextView embedded in each cell of my UITableView. Clicking the cell calls another view controller but clicking the textview inside the cell doesn't (but I want it to). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck User Interaction Enabled in the storyboard under the View category of the Attributes Inspector for your UITextView.